# How to work with message parts using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to click on a HTML link displayed in my email body. I am able to retrieve the message parts such as this:

```
0: { header:
{ from: xxxx@xxxxx.com,
to: yyyyy@yyyy.com,
subject: Test},
attrs:
{ struct:
[ { type: 'alternative',
params:
{ boundary: '--==_mimepart_5c889b3fd36c_46d2a1de845225',
charset: 'UTF-8' },
disposition: null,
language: null },
[ { partID: '1',
type: 'text',
subtype: 'plain',
params: [Object],
id: null,
description: null,
encoding: '7BIT',
size: 672,
lines: 14,
md5: null,
disposition: null,
language: null } ],
[ { partID: '2',
type: 'text',
subtype: 'html',
params: [Object],
id: null,
description: null,
encoding: '7BIT',
size: 1504,
lines: 31,
md5: null,
disposition: null,
language: null } ] ],
date: 2019-03-13T05:55:11.000Z,
flags: [],
uid: 102408,
modseq: '6535141',
'x-gm-labels': [ '\Important' ],
'x-gm-msgid': '1627868638473910311',
'x-gm-thrid': '1627868222319883033' } }
```

I have part 2 here displaying as HTML for "subtype". How do I verify the link name based on the part received and click on it. I am basically looking at this site: https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap to code for IMAP.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: have you tried a regular expression to read the body and identify the links?

Comment: @tech-hawk - umm, no I am not aware on how do I proceed from here. Basically, I am newbie to Node.JS. Can you please provide any solution.

Comment: please read about regular expressions, get an expression of `url`. use `.match()` function to match the regular expression.